# What files are need to upload after composer required <package>?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.3

So my hosting company not support composer. and reuploading all Laravel framework php files are too much take time just for one composer package. what are files need to be uploaded to hosting after composer required?

all i know is "package" folder in `vendor` folder, `composer.json`, and "config" file in `config` folder. is there any other files and folder?

Comment: You need to upload the entirety of the `vendor` directory. If you don't have shell access, you might not need binaries in `vendor/bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you forget: Facades, ServiceProvider

Answer (score 2):

You must upload `vendor/composer` and `vendor/autoload.php` too..

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is reupload all vendor directory. or track all vendor directory using git, so you can archive the different after update composer and upload it